# Webpart squezzed after jQuery hide() and show()

Tags: 2013, web-part, jquery

I have the following problem:

1. I exported on the mysite `https://mysite.intranet.i/personal/user/AllTasks.aspx` the tasks webpart.
2. I imported it on another page in another Sitecollection -> works, all tasks were shown
3. Now I made a button (CEWP) which uses the jQuery funktions `.hide()` and `.show()` on the div of the webpart which contains the tasks -> works
4. View settings were saved in the LocalStorage. The user sees the page how he was leaving it -> works

When I load the page with activated tasks there is no problem. I can activate/deactivate them and it's looking fine.

The problem is when I load the page without showing the tasks and then I activate it, the webpart is squeezed.

EDIT:

```
var divTasks = "#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6";
$("#imgTasks").click(function () {
   if (localStorage.getItem("task") == "false") {
      $(divTasks).show();
      localStorage.setItem("tasks", "true");
   } else {
      $(divTasks).hide();
      localStorage.setItem("tasks", "false");
   }
});
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: may be you need to check the logic. Please paste the code

Comment: SP acts weird in a lot of cases. I guess there is formatting done clientside that cant be done when the webpart is hidden.

If you post your code and maybe a picture of the squeezed webpart, you may will get better responses.